# How to redirect to the post overload of an IActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm working on an `Apsp.Net 6` project targeted `.Net6`.

I have this ActionResult:

```
    [Route( nameof(Recreate))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Recreate()
    {
       //Some code here
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route( nameof(Recreate))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Recreate(StudentYearlyResultReCreateVm model)
    {
       //Some code here
    }
```

Now I have another `ActionResult` described like this :

```
    [Route( nameof(RecreateWithId))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RecreateWithId(int id)
    {
        var result = await _studentYearlyResultRepository.GetByIdAsync( id );
        var modelObj = new StudentYearlyResultReCreateVm() {StudentId = result.StudentId , AcademicYearId = result.AcademicYearId};

        return RedirectToAction( nameof( Recreate ) , modelObj );
    }
```

**The problem :**
The problem is in `RecreateWithId` method I try to `RedirectToAction` to the post overload for `Recreate` action, but all I got is just redirected to the Get one.

**So please how I can redirect to the post overload of `Recreate` ?**
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot "redirect" to a POST endpoint. Are you entirely sure this is what you want to do, and not just execute the code of the POST endpoint?

Comment: Exactly I wanna execute the code

Comment: So what you need is not a redirection of any type. What you want to do is to create a service that has the necessary business logic, inject it into the controller and then use it in both actions

Comment: is good to create a private method in the controller and re-use it ?

Answer (score 1):

A quick, maybe dirty(?), solution.

```
[Route( nameof(RecreateWithId))]
public async Task<IActionResult> RecreateWithId(int id)
{
    var result = await _studentYearlyResultRepository.GetByIdAsync( id );
    var modelObj = new StudentYearlyResultReCreateVm() {StudentId = result.StudentId , AcademicYearId = result.AcademicYearId};

    return await Recreate(modelObj );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you return an action using `RedirectToAction`, the server returns a [3xx Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) to browser with `Location` header to that Url. Browser then proceeds to access that URL with `GET` verb, there is no way to change this unless you use Javascript to submit a form from that `GET` Url.

As for your question, I think a good solution should separation of concern by having a Service for processing:

```cs
[Route("api")]
public class ApiController
{

    ApiService service;
    public ApiController(ApiService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    [HttpGet, Route("")]
    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        await this.service.DoSomethingAsync();
    }

    [HttpPost, Route("")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        await this.service.DoSomethingElseAsync();

        // If you call this, don't redirect or it may call DoSomethingAsync twice
        await this.service.DoSomethingAsync();
        
        return this.RedirectToAction(nameof("OnGetAsync"));
    }

}
```